# Processing Arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, heap-dump

An Example demonstrating Passing an array as argument

```
#include <iostream>
#include <malloc.h>
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned char U8;

#define MAX_LEN 20

void func1(U8* arr)
{
 printf(" Passing Base address Element1 = %s\n",arr);    
}     

void func2(U8* arr)
{
 printf(" Passing Pointer address Element1 = %s \n",arr);    
}

int main()
{

 U8 arr[MAX_LEN] = "Stack Overflow\n";
 U8* arr1 = (U8*)malloc(sizeof(MAX_LEN));
 func1(arr); /* Passing Base address */
 memcpy(arr1,arr,sizeof(arr));
 /*      
 memcpy(arr1,arr,sizeof(MAX_LEN)); Leads to Heap Corruption why ?
 */
 func2(arr1);/* Passing pointer */
 free(arr1); 
 cout << "Array Freed" << endl;
 cin.get();   
 return 0;   
}
```

Queries :
1. which is the best Practise in consideration with data Processing.[data on stack or Heap] 
2. Please suggest reliable methodology to be used for such cases

Comment: Don't use `<malloc.h>`. It's not what you think.

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to mix c with c++.

Comment: Are you writing in C or in C++? If you are writing C++ code, I strongly recommend using standard containers like std::vector or std::array instead of hand-crafted pointer/malloc/free-gymnastics.

Comment: Kerrek SB :  Please Provide some Link to understand when one should inlcude or not .. "malloc.h" .. till then i will google it

Comment: @PragRao: One should use it **only** if one needs a function from it. And `malloc()` comes from `"stdlib.h"` instead, which is missing from this code sample.

Comment: Guess what?  You're not passing an array as an argument -- you're passing a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

```
memcpy(arr1,arr,sizeof(MAX_LEN)); // Leads to Heap Corruption why ?
```

Because `sizeof(MAX_LEN)` is equivalent to `sizeof(20)` which is equivalent to `sizeof(int)`.
This means you'll copy 4 or 8 bytes (depending on your platform). In `fun1` you then print the array as if it were a null terminated string. There is no null terminator though, since you didn't copy it and `printf` happily runs out of bounds.

`sizeof(arr)`, on the other hand, gives you correct size of 20.

`sizeof` operator queries the size of the **type of the expression** you give it as operand, not the value. It's purely compile time operator. The type of integer literal `20` is `int` and it'll return the size of that type.

Comment: Hi Jrok !!

Thanks for your comment !!

I am confused bit Now !! Please respond to this one

When i declare a Macro its Expanded rit 

when i write sizeof(MAX_LEN) it should be sizeof(20). am i correct .. then why it allcoates size as 4 .
And as my array is U8... 1 byte whts wrong ?
I checked it in my compiler : its surprsing  .. 

Output
 printf("Arr Len = %d",sizeof(arr));
 printf("Max Len = %d",sizeof(MAX_LEN));
 Arr Len = 20
 Max Len = 4

Answer (score 0):

Honestly? If you write in C++, simply use `std::vector`, pass it by reference and forget about the whole problem.

If you *really* have to use C-style arrays, I'd say, that *in most cases* (I mean, 99.9%), you'll have to allocate the array on the heap, because programs usually have limited stack memory available and placing an array there is generally not a good idea.

Remember though, that constant text expressions defined in the following way:

```
const char * myText = "Alice has a cat";
```

may not be stored on the stack, but somewhere (depending on C++ compiler). These won't occupy place on the stack and mostly probably this is the case in your example. In this example, a *pointer* to that text is stored on the stack, but the text itself is (mostly probably) stored elsewhere.